# getting common nodes between two tags

Tags: php, sql, mysql, drupal

i have a table with 2 columns tid and nid columns, i need to prepare a report to get common nodes between a tid.  i.e table is  like (tid, nid) (mysql,2) (mysql,3) (ajax,1) (ajax, 2)

now i need to get what   what are the common nodes between ajax and mysql which is node2.
i am looking for a query or some logic with database query in php

Adv thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this just for two specific tags, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT t1.nid
FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.nid=t2.nid
WHERE t1.tid='mysql' AND t2.tid='ajax'
```